# apache commons: FailableFunction and Function inside same FailableStream

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-lang3

Is there any way to use both `FailableFunction` and `Function` lambdas into a single `.map` chaining stream?

```
Function<String, Organization> hook = (id) -> this.organizationRepository.findById(id).get();
FailableFunction<Organization, Organization, MpiException> failableSave = (r) -> this.organizationRepository.save(r);

List<String> ids;

Failable.stream(ids)
   .map(hook)
   .map(failableSave)
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I'm getting:

> The method map(FailableFunction<String,R,?>) in the type Streams.FailableStream is not applicable for the arguments (Function<String,Organization>)

Problem here is that sometimes I need to use `Function` and other times I need to use `FailableFunction`.

Any ideas about how to use them into same stream `mapping` chaining?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but since nobody else came up with something:

You could use a method reference to implicitly convert a Function into a FailableFunction:

```
Failable.stream(ids)
   .map(hook::apply)
   .map(failableSave)
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```